# What do the letters "mi" mean in the commit dialog in the Tortoise SVN tool?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

A colleague of mine wanted to transfer something via the SVN tool from Tortoise (version 1.9.2.) but in the commit dialog you could suddenly see the letters "mi" as a symbol over the directory symbol.

I couldn't find anything information that describes that on their webpage and nothing so far on the internet. Maybe someone here has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the dialogue documentation with the "Help" button. Once there, click on:

> For information on the coloring and overlays of the items according to their status, please see Section 4.7.3, “Local and Remote Status”.

... and scroll down to:

> Overlay icons are used to indicate other states as well. The screenshot below shows all the possible overlays that are shown if necessary

And to answer your question:

> Items that have property modifications, but only to the `svn:mergeinfo` property. If any other property is modified, the overlay is not used.

Comment: Ah now I see the symbol! It was so small I didn't recognize it! Embarrasing....but thank you very much!